# Create .xls(biff) Excel Application

Tags: c#, excel

I have a routine that creates an excel file. The code uses:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

which creates the file as .xlsx by default.
How can I modfiy this code to create the file in .xls format?

Comment: are you sure that it creates `.xlsx` and not `.xls`. According to me it would be creating `.xls` not `.xlsx`

Comment: Yes, the ApplicationOpenXml create .xlsx, an xml file format....xls is a binary file format